# Help Writing an AppleScript that waits for a Ping

Tags: network, applescript, command-line, wifi, ping

I'm trying to make an AppleScript wait until there's a successful ping of a local IP or URL before continuing. I want this to work with no WiFi or ethernet and basically, be retrying until one of those connections is up and running.

The problem is that "do shell script" returns an error of unknown host if there's no network connection and breaks my script.

Here's my starting point script:

```
set ping to do shell script "ping -c 2 -q google.com"

repeat until ping contains "2 packets received"
   
   delay 1
   
end repeat
display dialog "Connection Successful." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

I've tried adding "try" commands and "repeat until" commands but nothing will get around that error.

ANY help is much appreciated!

Comment: What’s the next thing you do in the script?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you're running the `ping` test once at the beginning, storing the result, and then just checking that same result over and over. But it's a stored result, so it's never going to change unless you re-run the test.

Second, you do need a `try` block to catch errors from the `ping` command. In fact, you don't really need to store the result at all, just use the fact that if the `ping` fails, it'll skip the rest of the `try` section. Something like this:

```
repeat
    try
        do shell script "ping -c 2 -q www.google.com"
        exit repeat
    on error
        delay 1
    end try
end repeat
display dialog "Connection Successful." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

...so if the `ping` succeeds, it'll run the `exit repeat` command. If it doesn't, it runs the `on error` section instead, which delays a second (and *doesn't* exit the `repeat`, so the loop will run again).

[EDIT] If you want it to time out after a 10 seconds, you can record the start time at the beginning, then each time that the `ping` fails check whether it's been more than 10 seconds and display the failure message if to. The other thing that needs changing is that since the "Connection Successful." message should only be displayed if it succeeded, not if it exited the loop because of timeout, that message needs to be moved into the "success" condition inside the loop:

set startTime to (current date)

```
repeat
    try
        do shell script "ping -c 2 -q www.google.com"
        display dialog "Connection Successful." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        exit repeat
    on error
        if ((current date) - startTime) > 10 then
            display dialog "Connection timed out." buttons {"OK"} default button 1
            exit repeat
        else
            delay 1
        end if
    end try
end repeat
```

(Note: it might be tempting to use `repeat while ((current date) - startTime) > 10`, but that makes it harder to tell if the loop exited because of success or a timeout. IMO it's simpler to include the detect-finished-condition + display-message + exit-loop stuff as blocks inside the loop.)

Comment: Thank you! This all makes sense and helps me to better comprehend the logic of Applescript.

Comment: How could I add a timeout to this to where if after say 10 seconds it can't ping, it gives a customizable error?

Comment: @Mike See edit.

Comment: this is so helpful. Thank you so much for taking the time to teach me! I want to learn! And thanks for helping me solve the problem because this is going to be very usable for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming into this a little late, but I read how eager you are to learn AppleScript and the like, so I thought you might like to see an approach to your problem that is solved purely with AppleScript.

The problem as you stated it was a need to determine if a remote host is reachable, which I presume is a means of determining whether or not your machine has access to the internet.  In your example, you've established this by `ping`'ing `google.com`.

Instead of pinging an host, it's sufficient just to see whether its host name resolves.

<sup>***The technical jargon:** A **host name** is the readable, canonical form that a remote host goes by (such as "google.com"), but in order to connect to it, it first needs to be transformed (resolved) into an IP address (such as 142.250.187.195), which provides a machine with the location of the host on the internet.  This is referred to as **host name resolution** or **domain name resolution**, and is performed by a **domain name server**.*</sup>

If a remote hostname successfully resolves, then you have access to the internet, and very likely, your script can continue onward.  The benefit of this method compared with a `ping` is that the ping relies on the the remote host being up-and-running and connected to the internet (of course, Google probably hasn't disconnected since the 90s); and it requires that the host being pinged chooses to reply to the ping (they aren't obliged to).  DNS resolution will occur regardless of whether the host is currently responding, and it's a necessary action that must occur for your machine to be able to access the internet.  If it fails, then it's likely you won't be able to access any website, which in your case sounds like a reasonable test to determine whether any of your ethernet connections are active.

Anyway, here's the AppleScript handler:

```
on hostIsReachable at address as {record, text}
        tell (the address as {URL, anything}) to if ¬
                    (string ≠ its class) then tell ¬
                    the host to set the address to ¬
                    the DNS form
    
        tell ("mailto:" & the address) as URL to tell ¬
                    host & {dotted decimal form:stop} ¬
                    to its dotted decimal form ≠ stop
end hostIsReachable
```

You can paste this at the start or end of your script where you may have other handlers lurking already.  The handler can be invoked whenever you need to use it like so:

```
hostIsReachable at "https://www.google.com" --> true
```

or:

```
hostIsReachable at "google.com" --> true
```

or:

```
hostIsReachable at "google" --> true
```

It returns **`true`** if the host name or URL you supplied is one that would be expected to resolve and you have an active internet connection for the resolution to take place; it returns **`false`** otherwise.  So, this:

```
hostIsReachable at "asdfghjkl.com" --> false
```

will return *`false`* because that domain name is not registered on the internet.  Additionally, using an IP address will always return *`true`*, which makes sense if you consider that the nature of the test is to determine whether we get an IP address back after feeding it some data—if that data is already an IP address, then there's not a whole lot of resolution left to do.

You can slot this test into a loop for polling:

```
repeat 20 times -- 20 × 0.5-second delays = 10 seconds
        set connected to hostIsReachable at "google.com"
        if connected then exit repeat
        delay 0.5 -- (in seconds)
end repeat

if not connected then error "Timeout waiting for connection."
            .
            .
            .
(* rest of your script *)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share this answer! Definitely taking it in and playing around with it.